# Morse potential and chaos

Tags: schroedinger-equation, chaos-theory

I have heard that the Morse potential equation

$$\tag{1} -\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m} \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y(x)+ae^{bx}y(x)-E_{n}y(x)=0 $$

is related to the two dimensional equation on the Poincare half plane with a constant magnetic field

$$\tag{2} -\frac{y^{2}}{2m}( \partial _{x}^{2}+\partial _{y}^{2})f(x,y)+B\partial_{y}f(x,y) = 0$$

by means of a substitution that turns (2) into (1) but i do not know where to find some free avaliable info.

Comment: __1.__ Don't you want to write the potential as $V(x) = D_e (1-e^{-a(x-x_e)})^2$, as for example in this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential)? The form you wrote, $V(x) = a e^{bx}$, is different, and I don't think it is the Morse potential any more. __2.__ Could you maybe explain the relation of this problem to _chaos_? Or maybe the question title should be "Equivalence of solutions of Morse potential and a particle in constant magnetc field" (or something similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant article is: **The path integral on the Poincaré upper half-plane with a magnetic field and for the Morse potential** by **Christian Grosche** http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003491688902837

> Abstract Rigorous path integral treatments on the Poincaré upper
>   half-plane with a magnetic field and for the Morse potential are
>   presented. The calculation starts with the path integral on the
>   Poincaré upper half-plane with a magnetic field. By a Fourier
>   expansion and a non-linear transformation this problem is reformulated
>   in terms of the path integral for the Morse potential. This latter
>   problem can be reduced by an appropriate space-time transformation to
>   the path integral for the harmonic oscillator with generalised angular
>   momentum, a technique which has been developed in recent years. The
>   well-known solution for the last problem enables one to give explicit
>   expressions for the Feynman kernels for the Morse potential and for
>   the Poincaré upper half-plane with magnetic field, respectively. The
>   wavefunctions and the energy spectrum for the bound and scattering
>   states are given, respectively.

However, it is not freely available. For some information you can consult http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9302053 - **Classification of Solvable Feynman Path Integrals** co-authored by C. Grosche -  in the table at the end of article the authors claim that Schroedinger equation for both Morse potential and particle in constant magnetic field can be viewed as generalisations of radial harmonic oscillator problem. Unfortunately they don't give much details.

Comment: A free pdf file of Grosche's article is available [here](http://www-library.desy.de/preparch/desy/postpr/1988/desy88-045.pdf).